# ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding, postgres-10

I am in the middle of migrating some queries which have been running for ages with MySQL database which is now in Postgres having the same structure. I got stuck with a simple round function which ends with the following error message.

> ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

part of the select which does not work:

```
round(floor(pools.available_capacity_in_kb/1024/1024/1024*100)/100,2) as free,
```

`pools.available_capacity_in_kb` is stored as BIGINT in the database (Postgres 10.9)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The core of the problem is somewhere else. PostgreSQL uses long division for integer and bigint numbers (when on both parts of division are int, bigint values). So result of `pools.available_capacity_in_kb/1024/1024/1024*100)/100` is bigint. Probably this is not, what you expect.

```
postgres=# \df round
                          List of functions
+------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+------+
|   Schema   | Name  | Result data type | Argument data types | Type |
+------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+------+
| pg_catalog | round | double precision | double precision    | func |
| pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric             | func |
| pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric, integer    | func |
+------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+------+
(3 rows)
```

There is not any `round` function for `bigint` (because it has not any sense).
Please try to fix it by using float division like

```
pools.available_capacity_in_kb/1024/1024/1024*100)/100.0
```

Now, the result will be `numeric`, and the function `round(numeric, int)` exists - so it should works.

Comment: The function sequence "round(floor( ..." is not necessary, and does not make since anyway. The [floor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-math.html)  function returns "the largest **integer** less that or equal to the argument", You cannot round an integer - at least not without an UDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick turnaround Pavel. You are right - round function is not working on bigint. I changed data type to numeric and that worked well. round(floor(pools.available_capacity_in_kb::numeric/1024/1024/1024*100)/100,2) as free,

Comment: @radeklopatecki so please, close this task

Comment: Is there a SQL equivalent to `\df`?

Comment: @Rafs - `select oid::regprocedure from pg_proc where proname like '%round%';`

Answer (score 69):

I had the same problem with geographic coordinates. The longitude was in double precision from the open street map data and needed a rouded value.

My solution work fine:

```
select ROUND(CAST(longitude AS numeric),2) from my_points;
```

Comment: The solution worked for me when I ran into the issue while using Postgres 9.6 in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com)

Answer (score 43):

Besides the type CAST syntax, you can use the following syntax to convert a value of one type into another `(cast :: operator)`:

```
select ROUND(value::numeric, 2) from table_x;
```

Notice that the cast syntax with the cast operator (::) is PostgreSQL-specific and does not conform to the SQL standard.

Comment: I was having an expression inside the round function as first parameter, that expression was returning 'double precision' value. After so much efforts I finally could solve the issue by enclosing the expression in bracket and type casting the result to numeric. Thanks to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use following syntax as well

```
select round((value::Decimal),2) from table_name;
```

Notice that the cast syntax with the cast operator (::) is PostgreSQL-specific and does not conform to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the column that I was trying to aggregate with **AVG()** was been returned as a Set (look at the error message: "*ERROR: function avg(double precision[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts*").

So, the solution in my case was to do a SubQuery and use the **Unnest()** function, this way:

```
Select avg(unnested_field) from
( 
      Select unnest(field) as unnested_field
      From my_table
) as Subquery
```